# Is there no need to reap zombie process in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

It seems to me in Python, there is no need to reap zombie processes.

For example, in the following code

```
    import multiprocessing
    import time

    def func(msg):
        time.sleep(2)
        print "done " + str(msg)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        for i in range(10):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=('3'))
            p.start()
            print "child"+str(i)
        print "parent"
        time.sleep(100)
```

When all the child process exit, the parent process is still running
and at this time, I checked the process using `ps -ef`
and I noticed there is no defunct process.

Does this mean that in Python, there is no need to reap zombie process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a look to the library - especially to `multiprocessing/process.py` -, I see that

1. in `Process.start()`, there is a `_current_process._children.add(self)` which adds the started process to a list/set/whatever,
2. a few lines above, there is a `_cleanup()` which polls and discards terminated processes, removing zombies.

But that doesn't explain why your code doesn't produce zombies, as the childs wait a while befor terminating, so that the parent's `start()` calls don't notice that yet.

Comment: I don't get your point in you last sentence, accroding to your 1 and 2, the zombies are cleaned up by the Process class itself?

Comment: @user1944267 Yes, but under certain circumstances, wich are not fulfilled in this situation. I tried to put some light into the shed, but it was not bright enough.

Comment: besides, if I want to do something after all the child processes exit, how to make this possible? like the `wait()` in `C`

Answer (score 1):

Those processes are not actually zombies since they should terminate successfully. 
You could set the child processes to be deamonic so they'll terminate if the main process terminates.

Comment: I don'tthink so :) Still might be missunderstanding something.